# How to set the default character-set?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a new db in mysql.
I set utf8 as the default-character-set, but when I attempted to restart the db, mysql failed to restart and posted the following prompt:

Trying to start the server ...
Could not re-connect to the MySQL Server.
Server could not be started.

Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8'

Aborting

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete

I know that after cancelling the default-character-set, mysql will restart. But if I *had* to set the default-character-set, is there some other way to make mysql work again?

Comment: Did you set this in the config file for mysql?
Try character-set-server=utf8

Comment: i have ready try it,but it still post the same prompt and cann't restart yet

Comment: Yes, in the "my.ini".
default-character-set is deprecated in 5.5
This link might be of use: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-configuration.html
or maybe look for some example configuration files that came with mysql. Already created a db?

Comment: yes,i have aready created.I firtstly set it in the mysql 5's administration gui,will it be any compatible mistakens?

Comment: And by the way,have u ever used the mysql5.5's workbench before?i want to settd up a new db throgh the restore page,but unfortunately i haven't found any detail about creating a new db using sql file in the restore page.Do u know whre this manufication detail switch to !?

Comment: @kaiwiiho: The best way for you is to specify character set when creating a database, e.g. `create database DD default character set utf8`. So you are not dependant on MySQL server settings then.

Comment: Also relative answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf/3513812#3513812).

Answer (score 32):

I had a similar problem. The answer, as EO2 pointed out, is that default-character-set is deprecated in 5.5. You should use instead:

```
character-set-server = utf8
```

BTW, it's better if answers are answered as answers, not comments... ;-)

Comment: In what section of the `my.cnf` would you put this?

Comment: I get `Unknown option: character-set-server`, But if I add a "mysqld" section and add it there, it works without error. it is important, because in the "client" section this won't work (I am not sure if it has an effect though jet)

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem when running mysqlslap i get the following error:

```
mysqlslap unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8mb4'
```

After a lot of investigations i discovered that `default-character-set` was being set in another file instead of all the config files i changed.

The option was set in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-client.cnf`, so i just commented this line `default-character-set = utf8mb4` and everything went well.

I have MySQL running on Debian 9. that in case someone is having the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue today, but with version 5.7.31. For me commenting the line did work but.. how to set the character set in config files then ?

There's a reply: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html

So, to specify character settings at server startup we can for example add these lines in two files (for me these were: **50-client.cnf** and **50-mysql-clients.cnf** - both in **/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/ directory**):

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Remember about the "**mysqld**" section, it is important, because in the "client" section this won't work.

Comment: in `./mariadb.conf.d/50-client.cnf` I had no `[mysql]` section, so I added it

Comment: Yes, remove any character-set from `[client]` section and add a section `[mysqld]` with values as suggested by @elvisef.