# Client can not connect mysql server - Unknown Charset

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, client

i tried to work on mysql.
I follow these steps in that link:

http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/MySQL_HowTo.html

But i can't connect a server. I start the mysql server its ok. but when i'm enter the following line in cmd;

**mysql -u root**

i receive that message:

**mysql: Unknown OS character set 'cp857'. 
mysql: Switching to the default character set 'latin1'.**

i waited about 5 min nothings changed. Need help
thanks.

**UPDATE**

I fix the charset problem but i noticed now it was not my big problem. I'm still can't connect the server i'm waiting in black screnn cmd.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set the default character-set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720937/how-to-set-the-default-character-set)

Comment: i tried that before and i noticed someting now. I think my problem is not about charsets. now i'm add this line :default-character-set=utf8 and now i'm still waiting in black screen Nothings changed

Comment: did you try to restart the service ? `service mysqld restart`

Comment: Please *do not* edit your solution into the question. Post an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

**I solved the problem by myself. It's because of AVAST! FREE EDITION i shut down all shields and then connect succesfully.**
Thanks.