# MySQL not starting after PHPMyAdmin update on XAMPP

Tags: mysql

I'm a .NET developer trying to develop some PHP applications.

I installed XAMPP on Windows without problems, then started correctly Apache and MySQL.

After that, to update my PHPMyAdmin version, I followed the following article:

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/update-phpmyadmin/

But after that my MySQL service is not starting anymore. If I open the log I read the following rows:

```
2016-12-21 23:22:26 21c4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 115186280 and 115186280 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 115186320 in the ib_logfiles!
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.32-79.0 started; log sequence number 115186320
2016-12-21 23:22:26 7700 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-12-21 23:22:26 8644 [ERROR] Fatal error: mysql.user table is damaged or in unsupported 3.20 format.
```

Anyone had the same problem?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

As someone pointed out, my error is the same as [Making MySQL work with utf-8 in my.cnf configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086444/making-mysql-work-with-utf-8-in-my-cnf-configuration-file)

However the solution for such case is not working for me.

I tried to execute the `mysql_upgrade` but the command is obviously not working because the mysql service is stopped.

**EDIT**

I reinstalled XAMPP from scratch and, like previous times, it started correctly. However, after a couple restarts it is not starting anymore (always the same error).

Comment: Phpmyadmin is a gui for mysql written in php. Installing, deinstalling, updating phpmyadmin have absolutely no bearings on the mysql server whatsoever. The error message actually tells you what the issue is.

Comment: I agree with you. So, why MySQL is not starting in your opinion?

Comment: The error message tells you why it is not starting.

Comment: Thank you. And why this error only after PHPMyAdmin update? I did nothing else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making MySQL work with utf-8 in my.cnf configuration file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086444/making-mysql-work-with-utf-8-in-my-cnf-configuration-file)

Comment: I don't think you just simply updated phpmyadmin. I think you also updated mysql server.

Comment: No, I didn't. I only replaced the content of **phpmyadmin** folder. I am not able to update mysql server :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131279/discussion-between-flea777-and-shadow).