# Creating DB in symfony2 with particular collation

Tags: symfony, doctrine, collation

I want to create DB with `utf8_general_ci` collation. I've defined the MySQL connection collation as utf8_general_ci (in phpmyadmin), and I've defined `charset:  UTF8` in config.yml but when I use `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`  it create a table with `latin1_swedish_ci` collation.
Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing is to change MySQL setting directly. Add this to your `my.ini` file (MYSQL configuration file):

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
default-collation=utf8_general_ci
```

I saw once a trick to do it directly from Symfony but it was requiring to change some internal code of Doctrine and it wasn't even working in my case.

I end up adding those settings to `my.ini` file.

**Edit**:
Some links on how to change charset and collation on MySQL

1. [change mysql default character set to UTF8 in
   my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3513773/697930)
2. [MySQL 5.0 Reference guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html)

Regards,
Matt

Comment: I did as you suggested, I stopped mysql service and now I can not run it back. Only when I delete these two lines I added in my.ini just so I can start the Mysql back.

Comment: Well. I did this: ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8

Comment: Did you add the three lines, `[mysqld]` is important. The alter should not have caused any problem.

Comment: This is odd, reading the reference guide says to do exactly this. Dunno what could go wrong. Sorry it don't work as expected ...