# Why is mysqli_fetch_fields() giving me inaccurate results?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The `length` result from `mysqli_fetch_fields()` is giving me inaccurate results.

MySQL > `DESCRIBE Notices;`

```
Field     Type               Null     Key     Default     Extra
Id        int(10) unsigned   NO       PRI     (NULL)      auto_increment
UserId    int(10) unsigned   NO       MUL     (NULL)
Title     char(255)          NO               (NULL)
Name      char(255)          NO               (NULL)
Summary   text               NO               (NULL)
```

However,

```
class Db {
    public function exec($sql) {
        if (!$this->link) {
            $this->open();
        }
        if (($this->result = mysqli_query($this->link, $sql)) === false) {
            throw new Exception('<b>' . __METHOD__ . '</b>: ' . $sql . ': ' . mysqli_error($this->link));
        }
        return true;
    }
    public function field_info($table) {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `' . $table . '` LIMIT 1';
        $this->exec($sql);
        return $this->field_info = $this->result->fetch_fields();
    }
}

$a  = $db->field_info('Notices');
print_r($a);
```

Produces the following output:

```
// Note: "max_length" is the maximum existing length in the result set,
// while "length" is the set maximum length in the table definition.

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Id
            [orgname] => Id
            [table] => Notices
            [orgtable] => Notices
            [def] =>
            [max_length] => 1
            [length] => 10
            [charsetnr] => 63
            [flags] => 49699
            [type] => 3
            [decimals] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => UserId
            [orgname] => UserId
            [table] => Notices
            [orgtable] => Notices
            [def] =>
            [max_length] => 1
            [length] => 10
            [charsetnr] => 63
            [flags] => 53289
            [type] => 3
            [decimals] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Title
            [orgname] => Title
            [table] => Notices
            [orgtable] => Notices
            [def] =>
            [max_length] => 27
            [length] => 765
            [charsetnr] => 33
            [flags] => 4097
            [type] => 254
            [decimals] => 0
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Name
            [orgname] => Name
            [table] => Notices
            [orgtable] => Notices
            [def] =>
            [max_length] => 25
            [length] => 765
            [charsetnr] => 33
            [flags] => 4097
            [type] => 254
            [decimals] => 0
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Summary
            [orgname] => Summary
            [table] => Notices
            [orgtable] => Notices
            [def] =>
            [max_length] => 26
            [length] => 196605
            [charsetnr] => 33
            [flags] => 4113
            [type] => 252
            [decimals] => 0
        )
)
```

If you look, you'll see that the reported lengths of the `CHAR` fields do not match. `DESCRIBE` is giving me `255`, while `fetch_fields()` is giving me `765`. Why?

(The idea, in case you're wondering, is to produce a `maxlength` attribute for `<input>` tags.)

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53261260#53261260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field length is 255 **characters**, but the reported length is in **bytes**.

Since MySQL is using [3 bytes per character](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) for UTF-8 collations, you get 255*3 = `765` as your result.

Comment: Where does it say that the length is in bytes? The [documentation for `mysqli_fetch_fields`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-fields-returnvalues) only says "The width of the field, as specified in the table definition.". Also you only get the incorrect result on Windows. When you run the same script on Linux you get the expected result, i.e. `255`.

Comment: @SebastianZartner. Nope. I was seeing trouble where both PHP and MySQL were running on Linux. (With both on Ubuntu; and again with both on CentOS.)

Comment: Right, the comment above was my perception from yesterday. Though as you can see in my answer below it is actually unrelated to the OS but rather defined through the default client character set.

Answer (score 1):

The `length` as well as the `charsetnr` values in the `mysqli_result::fetch_fields()` / `mysqli_fetch_fields()` output obviously depend on the default character set defined by the client.

E.g. a `charsetnr` of `33` stands for UTF-8. To be precise it actually stands for the collation 'utf8_general_ci' of the character set 'utf8'. That info can be retrieved by executing this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM information_schema.collations;
```

A list of available character sets and their character length can be retrieved via this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM information_schema.character_sets;
```

The default client charset can be changed by PHP calling `mysqli::set_charset()` / `mysqli_set_charset()`.

**Example:**

```
$dbHandle->set_charset('latin1');
```

The PHP documentation for `mysqli_fetch_fields()` currently doesn't include that info, so I requested to add it in [bug 68573](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68573).

The default character set can also be [defined within the server configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-configuration.html) as [described in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513812/432681).

As this behavior of `fetch_fields()` is quite confusing, I requested to change it in [bug 68574](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68574).

Answer (score 0):

I divide the result:

```php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from tabla");
$campoTD = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);
  foreach ($campoTD as $campo){
    echo '<input maxlength='.number_format($campo[$i]->length / 3).' >';
    $i++;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and found out you need to use:
$val->length;

not max_length, max_length is the max length of the values in that particular column not the table def.

If you want the table definition use 'length'.

```
$q = $mysqli->query("select * from table");

$finfo = $q->fetch_fields();

foreach ($finfo as $val) {

    echo $val->length;

}
```

ref: http://php.undmedlibrary.org/manual/de/function.mysqli-fetch-fields.php

Comment: Yes. See comment in code in my question, which already makes that point.