# mysql_fetch_array returns non-Unicode text

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

I've made a simple PHP page to get the POST data and fetch a sql query then print the result. I'm using the mysql_fetch_array function.

The code works great but the response is a non-Unicode text, and it returns something like this:

```
?????ABC?????
```

note that the database collation is UTF8 and data stored are shown correctly in phpMyAdmin. I even used this META tag in php page but it results the same:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Any idea?!

Comment: try setting character enconding for connection.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add these lines of code before the first query:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
```

Or you can edit your mysql configuration to use utf8 by default.  Check here for what you need to do.

[Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf)

## UPDATE

The function `mysql_query` is deprecated, so `mysqli` object can be used like so:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "MYSQL_USER", "MYSQL_PASS", "MYSQL_DB");

$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");  
$mysqli->query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
```

Where $link is a connection created with mysql_connect

Comment: according to PHP "This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future...Alternatives to this function include:
mysqli_set_charset()".  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Answer (score -1):

Try using **mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");** for details http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php