# UTF-8 French accented characters issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, character-encoding

When i see data as stored on mysql database using phpmyadmin, the characters are stored exactly as é à ç however when i use php to display these data on an html document that has the exact following structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I got square instead of accented character, however, i don't have this issue with any accented characters on static content that haven't been loaded from mysql in the same page.

when i see on the source code of the page they seem to be identical! for example:

part of static data on the source code displayed as:

```
éçà
```

part of mysql origin data:

```
éçà
```

i tried replacing

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

with

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1552" />
```

and as result i got mysql one fixed, static with squares !

any hints?

Comment: Looks like a misconfiguration issue. Maybe your DB drivers are not using UTF-8?

The fact that the data that comes from the DB shows OK when you change to `windows-1552` and the static files do not can mean that your source file is (correctly) in UTF-8, but the data from your DB is arriving in the wrong encoding format.

Whatever is going on, stick to UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i have checked the database and i found the Collation is set to `latin1_swedish_ci`, could that be the source of the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's the source of the problem, you are storing your data in ascii in mysql but then trying to show it as utf8 in your html..

Comment: Yes, that's the issue, most probably.

Comment: many choices at the `utf-8` menu level on phpmyadmin, which the right one should i pick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite common charset issue, you need to set connection encoding manually for MySQL connection (those should be first queries you execute after establishing connection):

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

And also make sure every table has `CHARACTER SET` set to `UTF-8`.

Or you could also update [server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf).

Comment: Fixed with `SET NAMES utf8;` executed as suggested. Thank you!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf for instructions on how to do this automatically on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a misconfiguration issue. Most probably your DB or drivers are not using UTF-8.

The fact that the data that comes from the DB shows OK when you change to `windows-1552` and the static files do not can mean that your source file is (correctly) in UTF-8, but the data from your DB is arriving in the wrong encoding format.

Whatever is going on, stick to UTF-8.

**UPDATE:** There is a thread that explains how to automatically set the encoding for the connection:

[Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf)

Comment: Thank you Pedro, the issue has been fixed and i won't stick to windows-1552.
where there's a term windows there's issues lol. thank you