# UnicodeEncodeError and inserting a data into db

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I have a Python scraper which scraper a web site and inserts a data into MySql db. All of a sudden I got an error of

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 39: ordinal not in range(256)` when I parsed the string which contains the sign of `EURO -- €1`.

I saw some articles describing how to solve this issue but didn't understand how to apply them to my issue. I just scrape the data using `BeautifulSoup`, I don't encode/decode it manually.

I use this module `import MySQLdb` to work with MySql.

So how do I get rid of this issue?

Comment: What character set did you use when you created the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problems befor,I think it because Python use unicode encoding as default,but mysql use latin as default encoding,if you mysql database do not support utf-8,please use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf)

simply you can add `default-character-set = utf8` under [client] in the mysql configure file and `character-set-server = utf8` under [mysqld].the mysql configure file in linux is `/etc/my.cnf`,I don't know the location in windows,you can find out youself.At the same time,you sould use `sql_con = MySQLdb.connect(host=MYSQL_ADDR , user=MYSQL_USER , passwd=MYSQL_PWD , db=MYSQL_DB , charset="utf8")` to connect mysql.for safety you can add `#coding: utf8` in your python code.attention,it a comment.by the way,you do not have to set encoding in mysql5.6.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 'latin-1' encoding in your table (You can check charset using `Show Create Table <table-name>;`), then you can replace all unknown characters with their HTML entities:

```
u'EURO -- €1'.encode('latin-1', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
# result is 'EURO -- &#8364;1'
```

If you're using Unicode encoding, just create a Unicode string with `u''` and pass it to DB.