# Can a single MySQL server support multiple encodings?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have one database that needs to be converted from `latin_1` to `utf8`. This conversion is no problem and in my staging environments, everything works correctly when I add to my.cnf the lines (as suggested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf)):

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

And run the appropriate ALTER statements:

```
ALTER TABLE {row} CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Unfortunately, this database doesn't sit on the MySQL server alone. It shares the server with a couple databases still using the `latin_1` encodings and these databases really have no need to be `utf8`. Can I have different encodings share the same server and do I need to alter the default configuration to do this? Or is this asking for trouble?

Comment: Should be no problem. We have a developer machine with many databases, some UTF-8 and Some Latin 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encoding of the actual data is on a per-column basis, i.e. every single column in every table could have a different encoding. The data is transcoded on the fly to/from the *connection encoding* each individual client has; each client can have a different connection encoding and each client can change the connection encoding on the fly. You do not need to change anything in the config files; in fact you shouldn't, since this may influence the behavior of clients relying on the default.

Just set your own encoding settings for your client and you're good. Read [this](http://kunststube.net/frontback) for more details.