# MYSQL is truncating string at first multi-byte character in utf8 mode

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8

I've created a new table with default charset utf8.  Then I insert some multi-byte char strings.

`mysql> insert into table1 (val,val1,val2) values ("aaaéfff poeuo","asdf","asdf");`

The insert is made without error.  When I select this row, the value in `val1` has been truncated to "aaa".  column `val` is defined as varchar(40).

I can't understand why the mysql won't take the utf8 chars.

I've set the default char set as described here: [Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf).

When I enter `show variables like 'char%';` everything is in utf8 mode.

What could be wrong?

Comment: I don't think that answers the question.  Its all about php.

Comment: Maybe. It illustrates the concepts though.