# heroku db:pull to local mysql utf8

Tags: mysql, heroku

I'm trying to dump a heroku db with heroku db:pull

The problem is that the data that has special character (like 'ñ') are not store propertly.

I see that the local tables are created with default charset=latin1

is there a way that the heroku script create the table with charset utf8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the default charset in mysql server itself like in:

[Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf)

doing that and after restart the local mysql, heroku db:pull will create the tables with the default utf8 charset.

Answer (score 1):

heroku db:push -t tables mysql://user:pass@localhost/mydb encoding=UTF8 --confirm myapp