# Setting correct innodb_log_file_size in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

We ran an alter table today today that took down the DB.  We failed over to the slave, and in the post-mortem, we discovered this in the mysql `error.log`

```
InnoDB: ERROR: the age of the last checkpoint is 90608129,
InnoDB: which exceeds the log group capacity 90593280.
InnoDB: If you are using big BLOB or TEXT rows, you must set the
InnoDB: combined size of log files at least 10 times bigger than the
InnoDB: largest such row.
```

This error rings true because we were working on a very large table that contains BLOB data types.

The [best answer](https://serverfault.com/a/293442/110839) we found online said

> To solve it, you need to stop MySQL cleanly (very important), delete the existing InnoDB log files (probably lb_logfile* in your MySQL data directory, unless you've moved them), then adjust the innodb_log_file_size to suit your needs, and then start MySQL again. This article from the MySQL performance blog might be instructive.

and in the comments

> Yes, the database server will effectively hang for any updates to InnoDB tables when the log fills up. It can cripple a site.

which is I guess what happened, based on our current (default) `innodb_log_file_size` of 48mb?

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb_log%';
+-----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name               | Value    |
+-----------------------------+----------+
| innodb_log_buffer_size      | 8388608  |
| innodb_log_compressed_pages | ON       |
| innodb_log_file_size        | 50331648 |
| innodb_log_files_in_group   | 2        |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir   | ./       |
+-----------------------------+----------+
```

So, this leads me to two pointed questions and one open-ended one:

1. How do we determine the largest row so we can set our `innodb_log_file_size` to be bigger than that?
2. What is the consequence of the action in step 1?  I'd read about long recovery times with bigger logs.
3. Is there anything else I should worry about regarding migrations, considering that we have a large table (650k rows, 6169.8GB) with unrestrained, variable length BLOB fields.

We're running mysql 5.6 and here's our `my.cnf`.

````
[mysqld]

#defaults
basedir                   = /opt/mysql/server-5.6
datadir                   = /var/lib/mysql
port                      = 3306
socket                    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
tmpdir                    = /tmp
bind-address              = 0.0.0.0

#logs
log_error                 = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days          = 4
slow_query_log            = on
long_query_time           = 1


innodb_buffer_pool_size   = 11G

#http://stackoverflow.com/a/10866836/182484
collation-server          = utf8_bin
init-connect              ='SET NAMES utf8'
init_connect              ='SET collation_connection = utf8_bin'
character-set-server      = utf8
max_allowed_packet        = 64M
skip-character-set-client-handshake

#cache
query_cache_size          = 268435456
query_cache_type          = 1
query_cache_limit         = 1048576
```
````

As a follow-up to the suggestions listed below, I began investigation into the file size of the table in question.  I ran a script that wrote the combined byte size of the three BLOB fields to a table called `pen_sizes`.  Here's the result of getting the largest byte size:

```
select pen_size as bytes,·
  pen_size  /  1024 / 1024 as mb,·
  pen_id from pen_sizes
  group by pen_id
  order by bytes desc
  limit 40

+---------+------------+--------+
| bytes   | mb         | pen_id |
+---------+------------+--------+
| 3542620 | 3.37850571 |  84816 |
| 3379107 | 3.22256756 |  74796 |
| 3019237 | 2.87936878 | 569726 |
| 3019237 | 2.87936878 | 576506 |
| 3019237 | 2.87936878 | 576507 |
| 2703177 | 2.57795048 | 346965 |
| 2703177 | 2.57795048 | 346964 |
| 2703177 | 2.57795048 |  93706 |
| 2064807 | 1.96915340 | 154627 |
| 2048592 | 1.95368958 | 237514 |
| 2000695 | 1.90801144 |  46798 |
| 1843034 | 1.75765419 | 231988 |
| 1843024 | 1.75764465 | 230423 |
| 1820514 | 1.73617744 |  76745 |
| 1795494 | 1.71231651 | 650208 |
| 1785353 | 1.70264530 |  74912 |
| 1754059 | 1.67280102 | 444932 |
| 1752609 | 1.67141819 |  76607 |
| 1711492 | 1.63220596 | 224574 |
| 1632405 | 1.55678272 |  76188 |
| 1500157 | 1.43066120 |  77256 |
| 1494572 | 1.42533493 | 137184 |
| 1478692 | 1.41019058 | 238547 |
| 1456973 | 1.38947773 | 181379 |
| 1433240 | 1.36684418 |  77631 |
| 1421452 | 1.35560226 | 102930 |
| 1383872 | 1.31976318 |  77627 |
| 1359317 | 1.29634571 | 454109 |
| 1355701 | 1.29289722 | 631811 |
| 1343621 | 1.28137684 |  75256 |
| 1343621 | 1.28137684 |  75257 |
| 1334071 | 1.27226925 |  77626 |
| 1327063 | 1.26558590 | 129731 |
| 1320627 | 1.25944805 | 636914 |
| 1231918 | 1.17484856 | 117269 |
| 1223975 | 1.16727352 |  75103 |
| 1220233 | 1.16370487 | 326462 |
| 1220233 | 1.16370487 | 326463 |
| 1203432 | 1.14768219 | 183967 |
| 1200373 | 1.14476490 | 420360 |
+---------+------------+--------+
```

This makes me believe that the average row size is closer to 1mb than the 10 suggested.  Maybe the table size I listed earlier includes the indexes, too?

I ran

```
SELECT table_name AS "Tables", 
round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) "Size in MB" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = 'codepen'

+-------------------+------------+
| Tables            | Size in MB |
+-------------------+------------+
...snip
| pens              |    6287.89 |
...snip
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**0. Preliminary information**

Your settings:

```
innodb_log_file_size = 50331648
innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
```

Therefore your "[log group capacity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size)" = 2 x 50331648 = 96 MB

**1. How to determine the largest row**

There is no direct method. But one can easily calculate the size of one given row [based on these tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html) (compression should not matter to us here, if, as I assume, rows are not compressed in the log files).

**2. Impact of `innodb_log_file_size`**

[Reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size):

> The larger the value, the less checkpoint flush activity is needed in the buffer pool, saving disk I/O. Larger log files also make crash recovery slower, although improvements to recovery performance in MySQL 5.5 and higher make the log file size less of a consideration.

**3. Anything else to worry about**

6169.8 GB / 650k rows = about 10 MB per row on average
This is a serious problem per se if you intend to use your database in a transactional, multi-user situation. Consider storing your `BLOB`'s as files outside of the database. Or, at least, store them in a separate MyISAM (non-transactional) table.

Comment: wonder how `innodb_log_file_size` is set?  I posted my entire my.cnf.  The default is 2x5...

Comment: Your server might be actually using a different configuration file ([see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html) for possible locations).

Comment: for posterity, the default for `innodb_log_file_size` is 48mb, not 2x5.

Comment: This was changed in v5.6.8. I didn't know, thanks for the heads up.