# Cant send long data to msql MEDIUMTEXT or MEDIUMBLOB

Tags: php, mysql

I can only send data when string contains 523264 characters. HELP!

```
include("conn.php");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO json_t (json_string) VALUES (?)");
$null = NULL;
$stmt->bind_param("b",$null);

$stmt->send_long_data(0, $json_to_save);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

i'v tried this but still same errors

> "Error executing prepared statement. Row size too large (> 8126).
>   Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or
>   ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of
>   768 bytes is stored inline."

Please HELP.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO json_t (json_string) VALUES (?)");
$null = NULL;
$stmt->bind_param("b",$null);

$max_allowed_packet = 100000;
if (!$stmt->bind_param('b', $null))
die("Error binding parameters. {$stmt->error}\n");
echo "<br/><br/>";
foreach(str_split($v, $max_allowed_packet) as $packet )
if (!$stmt->send_long_data(0, $packet))
die("Error sending long packet. {$stmt->error}\n");
echo "<br/><br/>";
if (!$stmt->execute())
die("Error executing prepared statement. {$stmt->error}\n");
```

OK problem solved. I changed engine to MyISAM.

Comment: Error executing prepared statement. Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.

Answer (score 0):

> Allows to send parameter data to the server in pieces (or chunks), e.g. if the size of a blob exceeds the size of max_allowed_packet. **This function can be called multiple times** to send the parts of a character or binary data value for a column, which must be one of the TEXT or BLOB datatypes.

Emphasis mine.

You need to break the string down yourself, for instance with `str_split($json_to_save, 100000);`, then call `send_long_data` for each piece to be sent as chunks to the MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of questions about this already.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75328/row-size-error-with-mysql/75333#75333

(I can't flag as duplicate)

The problem is your server setting of `innodb_log_file_size`

How to figure out a good setting:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18811422