# insert arabic to mysql from perl

Tags: mysql, perl, arabic

When trying to insert arabic into mysql from Perl, the arabic content is displayed in the database like `أ™إ أکآ³أکآ´أ™إ` but when I retrieve the value from the database it will display like `ÙØ³Ø´Ù` in the web page.

note that my database and table charset is utf8 and the COLLATE is utf8_general_ci.

Comment: First, you need to establish what went wrong: putting it in the database, getting it from the database, or displaying it in the web page.

Comment: Please provide the output of `local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($str));` before you placed it in the database and after you fetched it from the database.

Comment: Additionally, if you have phpMyAdmin, does the text look right using it?

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to insert and select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SET NAMES 'UTF8'` after connecting to MySQL:

```
my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:$base_name:$mysql_host_url";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user_db, $password_db) or die $DBI::errstr;
$dbh->do(qq{SET NAMES "utf8"});
```

As the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) says:

> SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL
>   statements to the server... It also specifies the character set that the server should
>   use for sending results back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for my question ,
this solution for mysql database

[Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf)