# Can one change MySQL's default assignment from character sets to collations?

Tags: mysql, collation, my.cnf

I set up a MySQL database, version 5.5.31. The default collation for the character set `utf8mb4` is `utf8mb4_general_ci` (as shown by `SHOW CHARACTER SET`). I would like to change this to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Is there any way to change the default assignment from character sets to collations? Or is it hard-coded and compiled into the MySQL binary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer my question. The referenced question shows how to set the default character set and encoding for the client-server connection. But it doesn't help if one creates a table specifying character set `utf8mb4` (without explicitly setting the collation) -- then the default collation `utf8mb4_general_ci` is used instead of the desired `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER DATABASE db_name CHARACTER SET utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

See the reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-database.html).

Comment: As this does change the CHAR SET for the database, it does not change it to be the standard CHAR SET when creating new SCHEMAS

Comment: TS wants to change the char set of database, or have i missunderstood the question?

Comment: When you `ALTER DATABASE db_name`, you change the setting of that database. But if you `CREATE DATABASE` it will still use the default settings of the server. Above code will not change that.