# Jelastic Glassfish Mysql Character Setting

Tags: java, mysql, character-encoding, glassfish, jelastic

I have an application running on Jelastic. The Java based web application is running on Glassfish and the database server is MySql.

I developed the project on Netbeans and there was no character problem when running the project on the local machine (Turkish Windows 8).

When running on Jelastic, there is no character problem related to the web pages. However, there is problem when form based interactions are called.

Some Turkish characters are not processed when a search query or customer registration tasks are executed. Those characters missing (recorded to the MySql as ?)are the ones differing from the Latin. For example "ö", which is also used in German is not the problem.

Problematic characters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Turkish_characters

As I said previously, I dont have such problem when working on local Glassfish rolled in Netbeans.

I checked out the phpMyAdmin server, and I think that some values (that are set by default such as latin1_swedish_ci) might be the cause for loss of Turkish characters.

I tried to change the values on , but those are reset to the defaults when the server is restarted. Could this be the source of my problem? If so, how could I set them permentantly?

Your kind support will be greatly appreciated.☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where exactly you are applied changes?

As I know these settings can be changed at **etc/my.cnf** via Jelastic Dashboard in MySQL.

Concerning Character Setting you will help this link:

[Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf8-in-my-cnf)

If the problem persists ask your hosting provider for help with this issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I havent used etc/my.cnf. I will check out the link you provide.☺

Comment: Well, the link helped alot. I The issue was resolved. Thanks alot.

Comment: @user3501359 it would really help others if you could explain what the problem was and how it was solved (e.g. what you had to change in my.cnf or otherwise what other changes you made)

Comment: Hi,    I used the etc/my.cnf (in jelastic dashboard) to configure character setting. I added the following lines and the character problem was resolved:


[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_turkish_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8