# UTF 8 Server / Client (mySQL 5.5.40-cll-lve, PHP 5.4.35)

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am running a virtual server. I have set anything (I can think of) to UTF-8 (apache, mysql, php).

Umlauts do work fine, but when I try to paste e.g.
„n“
(the quotes are where the problem is), in the database the „ is replaced by a EUR symbol.

Everything should be utf-8 and its driving me crazy...

my.cnf:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server=utf8mb4
```

I am stuck...

Comment: Found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf. I changed to utf8mb4. Text is not cut anymore, but still not correctly stored.

Comment: „ is replaced by €? now o.O

Comment: This is crazy! I have absolutly no clue where the chars are lost. Anything should be utf-8. :(((