# Export from SQL Server to MySQL encoding issue

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a MS-SQL server 2012 Express database with **Hebrew_CI_AS** collation.

Im using [MySQL Migration Toolkit](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to migrate the database to a MySql server.

The migration completes succefully but in the MySql the Hebrew strings show up as question marks **???**

During the migration this notice shows up:

> "Collation Hebrew_CI_AS migrated to utf8_general_ci"

I looked in the the MySql database and tables  and they actually have **latin1_swedish_ci** collation when created by the migration tool.

I tried to solve it by converting the MySql DB and tables to **utf8_general_ci** just before the Migration tool copies the data from SQL to MySql but this didn't help. tried this also with **Hebrew_general_ci** but it had the same result.

Any ideas how to copy the data with the Hebrew strings intact ?

Thanks

Comment: Setting the target tables and columns to an encoding of `Hebrew_general_ci` before the import should solve the problem. Maybe you need to set the connection encoding via some configuration in the "MySQL Migration Toolkit".

Comment: yes @feeela the solution was to edit the my.ini file with the correct encoding.thanks for pointing the direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution was to edit the my.ini mysql configuration file as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf)

with

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

that worked for me,

Hebrew is now showing