# wrong collation for column

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have legacy system running MySQL 5.0.67.
Columns collation is set to latin1_swedish_ci.
PHP scripts that get data from DB and generates page with `charset=windows-1257`.
In PHP page language specific characters are shown correctly.
When I look directly into DB data I can see that these characters are not shown properly. I see Rûta instead of Rūta, Agnë instead of Agnė.
I can't write to database or change its parameter.

When I run

```
SELECT a.Name COLLATE cp1257_general_ci FROM agent a
```

i get error

```
COLLATION 'cp1257_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
```

How to get data from db with proper characters?

EDIT:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';
character_set_client    latin1
character_set_connection    latin1
character_set_database  cp1257
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/local/share/mysql/charsets/
```

and

```
show variables like 'collation%';
collation_connection    latin1_swedish_ci
collation_database  cp1257_lithuanian_ci
collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci
```

Comment: Sounds more like an issue with your client than with the server or the data. And I doubt that the collation is your issue, more likely the character encoding of your client seems to be off. What client are you using?

Comment: I'm using DbVisualizer 9 it has connection encotig set to cp1257.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf?rq=1

Comment: Interestingly CONVERT(CONVERT(ColumnName USING binary) USING cp1257) shows characters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout if you are getting `latin1` from

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';
```

Then, In the mysql configuration (`my.cnf`) add the following lines, and restart mysql server

```
[mysqld]    
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
character-set-client-handshake = false
```

Finally check what you are getting from

```
mysql> show variables like 'collation%';
```

**For reference :**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-literal.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Work entirely with cp1257:

```
SET NAMES cp1257;
declare columns to be `CHARACTER SET cp1257`

mysql> SET NAMES cp1257;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                         |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | cp1257                                        |
| character_set_connection | cp1257                                        |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                        |
| character_set_results    | cp1257                                        |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                        |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                          |
```

Note that 3 Variables are set.

Plan B:  Use utf8 instead of cp1257.

The `SET NAMES` *must* match the encoding you have in the client.  If `ū` is the single byte hex `FB`, the you must use cp1257.  If it is the 2-byte hex `C5AB`, you must use utf8.

Independently, you can set the table columns to be either cp1257 or utf8.  cp1257 allows for only Lithuanian and a few other languages.  utf8 allows for all languages.

`FB` in latin1 renders as `û`, hence the incorrect string you got.