# Encoding problems from MySQLdb query result on python

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, mysql-python

I'm using the library `MySQLdb` for Python to access a database with entries in Portuguese, with a bunch of accents, which I then save to an Excel file using `xlsxwriter`. When I'm closing the workbook to save it, I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 59: invalid continuation byte
```

The result it's complaining about is:

```
u'QNO XX Conjunto YY, No. Casa ZZ, CEP: AAAAAAAA, Bras\xedlia /DF'
```

In specific, it should be `Brasília` instead of `Bras\xedlia`. How can I get the outputs to be encoded in a friendlier way? Do I have to replace `\xed` and the like with each possible accent individually?

--EDIT:

I know 0xED is `í` in  `latin-1` (`iso-8859-1`), and given the language (and information from the people in charge of the db) I think that's the right encoding. How do I turn a string that goes `'Bras\xedlia'` into one that goes `'Brasília'` in general, knowing that?

--EDIT:

If I try to use `str(that thing)` what I get is

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 52: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: You can instruct MySQL to translate the results to utf-8 by a `SET NAMES 'UTF8'` query. [More info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html).

Comment: Your text is not UTF8 encoded, it looks more like an iso-8859-x variant. You should identify the encoding and pass it as the `charset` argument to `connect()`, or do an explicit `decode()` on the string.

Comment: I have tried several explicit decodes on the string and either the `\xed` remains or it's replaced by some other kind of `\x`-something, never by the actual accent. Passing a charset argument gives me `Can't initialize character set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a problem with `xlswriter`, not python or MySQL.

0xED says the bytes coming in are latin1, not utf8, not ascii.  If you are stuck with 0xED, then do `SET NAMES latin1` so that python will communicate correctly with MySQL.  It does not matter whether the tables/columns are `CHARACTER SET latin1` or `utf8`, `SET NAMES` will cause the suitable conversion (if any) to happen during `INSERT`/`SELECT`/etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your charset of your fields and your table.

To do so run one of the following:

`mysql> ALTER TABLE <table> CONVERT <col> VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;` ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851320/convert-column-collation-to-table-database-default), [3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html))

**OR**

`mysql> ALTER TABLE <table> MODIFY <col> VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;` ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851320/convert-column-collation-to-table-database-default), [3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html))

I would prefer the first one.

Lastly, as Klaus D. said you need to connect to mysql with `charset="utf8"`, check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202726/writing-utf-8-string-to-mysql-with-python)