# Hibernate, MySQL Encoding does not work on debian

Tags: mysql, hibernate, encoding

I've made an application in Java EE that uses Hibernate to communicate with MySQL. It works perfectly on my Windows development machine, but I have problem on debian, where the application is deployed.

When I search for keyword with Polish letters(like ł, ą, ć, ó etc,) the result is ok on Windows, but on server, where I have imported the database it does not work.

Hibernate query looks like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Keyword.findByKeyword", query = "SELECT k FROM Keyword k WHERE k.keyword = :keyword")
```

and is called like this:

```
myEntityManager.createNamedQuery("Keyword.findByKeyword").setParameter("keyword", keyword).getSingleResult();
```

When I use mysql on debian via SSH and type in SELECT query manually:

```
SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE keyword = 'ser żółty';
```

it also works and return single result. Encoding and collations of tables and columns are also ok. In datasource configuration I've added

```
?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
```

parameters, but it also did not help. I thought that maybe there is a problem with encoding in data from request send by form, but the problem appears even if the parameter i.e. "ser żółty" is hardcoded in my repository class.

I also use Hibernate Search for indexing and the FullTextEntityManager return correct results with Polish letters.

I assume that there is some problem between Hibernate and MySQL, but I have no more ideas what could I change. Any suggestions?

Server Wildfly9.0.1, MySQL 5.6

Comment: `SELECT hex(col)` from the table for 'ser żółty'.  If it is correctly stored, then you will get `73657220C5BCC3B3C5827479`.  That should give us a clue of what direction to turn next.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply. I did SELECT hex(keyword) FROM keyword WHERE keyword = 'ser żółty'; and I got exactly  73657220C5BCC3B3C5827479. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was in encoding on the mysql server level. It was set to latin1 by default. To fix this follow this question [Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf) and edit your my.cnf file.