# Chinese characters in database prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, prepared-statement

I might have a simple problem of encoding but i can't figure it out.
I have addresses that can be in English or in Chinese in a MySQL database, so i used *utf8_unicode_ci* . I don't have problems retrieving my chinese characters from the database, but I can't use the chinese characters in a prepared request.

I explain:
If I type

```
$bdd= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:3306; dbname=****;charset=utf8', 'root', '');   
$list_business = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM business WHERE address LIKE N\'台灣台南市\' ');
$nb_business=$list_business->rowCount();
```

I will get one result, because one of the addresses contains "台灣台南市"
But if I try to use a prepared request:

```
$list_business = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM business WHERE address LIKE ? ');
$list_business->execute(array('%'.$_POST['address'].'%'));
$nb_business=$list_business->rowCount();
```

If $_POST['address'] is in English it works, in Chinese it doesn't :p

EDIT :

If i echo $_POST['address'] it shows the address in chinese that I input so that part is okay, although, if I echo the address from database it will look like this : "701\u53f0\u7063\u53f0\u5357\u5e02\u6771\u5340\u88d5\u8c50\u885775\u865f".

EDIT2:

When asking for show variables like 'char%'; I got this result

character_set_client      utf8mb4

character_set_connection  utf8mb4

character_set_database    latin1

character_set_filesystem  binary

character_set_results     utf8mb4

character_set_server      latin1

character_set_system      utf8

character_sets_dir        c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\share\charsets\

Please, help!

Thanks beforehand,

Q

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf

Comment: Could you try this instead ~ `prepare("SELECT * FROM business WHERE address LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')")` and `execute([$_POST['address']])`

Comment: I tried but it didn't change the output. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the encoding was correct everywhere, except for the browser itself, on the form i was using to test my php file. I don't get why Google Chrome would encode it as European although i saved the html file as UTF-8.
Anyways, problem is solved. Thanks for your help, guys =)

Comment: For Chinese, use utf8mb4 in place of utf8.

Answer (score 1):

have you set your language environment to "UTF-8"?
have you set your mysql character set to utf-8? 
in mysql ,exec "show variables like '%char%'; it should return

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you elaborate please? =)

Comment: like this mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

Comment: nop, still not working =/
Please see the Edit in my question

Comment: have you check your mysql character set? like the table I edited :)

Comment: so maybe you can try to set character_set_server = UTF8 and character_set_database =UTF8,and reinitial your database.

Comment: If i change it directly in mysql nothing happens.
So i looked for my.cnf, and turned out i only have my.ini
In my.ini, i don't see any line refeering to character_set_***
Should i add lines?

Comment: after add this two lines ,you should restart your mysql .and reinitial your database.

Comment: It had to be pasted in two different sections, now i've got my variables all set up for utf8 and i restarted mysql (i can check that all variables are utf8). However, i still have my initial problem. How do i reinitialize?

Comment: delete your old database ,and recreate it and insert the data with utf8

Comment: and have you try PDO::exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';"); before exec sql statement ?

Comment: so sorry to hear that :(

Answer (score 0):

try setting the character set of the page itself (if you haven't already).

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```