# how to encoding ddl's encoding whileing using spring-boot-jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Using `spring-boot-jpa` auto generate create mysql's table, but the encoding is latin1.

How to change the encode to UTF-8.

The config is:

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=root
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Try with `spring.datasource.sqlScriptEncoding=UTF-8`

Comment: As far I understand you're looking to the wrong direction: if Hibernate creates tables, it doesn't specify their encoding. MySQL uses their default encoding in this case. So, if I would be you, I will try to configure MySQL server and set default encoding here. Maybe this question could help you in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf

Comment: Do you talk about the encoding of the table column Character Set and Collation?

Comment: show create table history;

CREATE TABLE `history` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `name` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_symbol_date` (`symbol`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1273 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1  the encoding is latin1,I want to change to utf8

Answer (score 0):

Just change the "default collation"  in settings mysql server according Your demand, next drop and create schema (or table) again.