# MySql Setting Default Value of 'collation_connection'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, collation, my.cnf

I have a MySql 5.6 database where the database is using a collation of utf8_unicode_ci.  Every time I create a new table the table is created with utf8_unicode_ci, but the varchar columns are set with utf8_general_ci.

When I look at the variables I see the following

```
'collation_connection', 'utf8_general_ci'
'collation_database', 'utf8_unicode_ci'
```

I can manually execute, `SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci;` and then create my table and everything works as I'd like.

The question is, how can I set collation_connection by default?  I've tried setting via my.cnf using the article below, but I can't seem to get my connection to change.  Ideas?

[Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf)

Comment: so have you tried adding collation_connection=utf8_unicode_ci to your my.cnf?

Comment: `SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` will do it, but after you connect.

Comment: @gen That is an illegal configuration setting, and the `mysql` CLI will not start with it present in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure ['string to be executed by the server for each client that connects'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect), by including this line in `[mysqld]` section of my.cnf configuration file:

```
[mysqld]
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;'
```

Maybe better using `SET NAMES` (details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-names.html)):

```
[mysqld]
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;'
```

To set default charset and collation for new tables, you would specify:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

[Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-server.html) explains:

> The server character set and collation are used as default values if
> the database character set and collation are not specified in CREATE
> DATABASE statements. They have no other purpose.

Consider using `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8`. Reference [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb3.html).