# Mysql do not use UTF-8

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I create database like always:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_db CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

I have dumped states.sql which looks fine but when I dump them to database I see strange symbols and letters where POLISH chart should be.

When I try add from some answers:

```
default-character-set=utf8
character-set-server=utf8
default-collation=utf8_unicode_ci
```

to my.cf - mysql doesn't want to restart.

I can also say that when I do in phpmyadmin for example:

```
SELECT * FROM 'states' WHERE name = 'gorzów'
```

I got error from mysql syntax with non utf-8 symbols.

Where can be problem?

Comment: Have a look here [3513773](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773) and / or here [8288](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8288)

Answer (score 0):

Did `gorzów` turn into `gorzÃ³w`?  That would be Mojibake.

This is the classic case of

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

Since you did not state what client you are using, nor what syntax you used for connecting, I can't be more specific.  Perhaps http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python, or the sections that follow, will help.