# In MySQL, what do I put inside my.cnf so that all tables are UTF-8 that works with emojis by default?

Tags: mysql, database

I'd like every table and database (to be created) to be utf-8 that works with emojis.  I understand that there are a few variables I need to define inside `my.cnf`:

```
init_connect='SET collation_connection = ??? '
init_connect='SET NAMES ???'
character-set-server = ???
collation-server = ???
```

However, I'm not sure what to put in the `???`.  What do I put inside `my.cnf`?

Comment: Does this post answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to support UTF-8 completely in a web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/how-to-support-utf-8-completely-in-a-web-application) ... Many more questions about this as well btw...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This article may help: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4

It explains in detail how to switch to `utf8mb4` to support full unicode, thus allowing emojis using the following config:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to changing to `utf8mb4` as @eol suggests, there may be more to do.

If you already have tables that have `utf8` columns; do `ALTER TABLE .. CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

When you connect, be sure to establish `UTF-8` if the client has a non-mysql way of doing it, or use `SET NAMES utf8mb4`.

Keep in mind that `root` ignores `init-connect`.  You *should* have a non-root 'user' for the application.

Answer (score 2):

To support full Unicode in MySQL databases

1. For database: `ALTER DATABASE DATABASE_NAME CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`
2. For table:
   `ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`
3. For column: `ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME CHANGE COLUMN_NAME COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`