# Mysql 5.5 how to set up everything to utf8?

Tags: mysql

I just want everything default to utf8. I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf) but nothing help.

Currently, My `/etc/my.cnf` is

```
[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

But when I restart the server, create a new database, it is still latin1(`character_set_database` and `character_set_server`):

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'collation%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I create a database, It is latin1:

```
mysql> create database d1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use d1;
Database changed
mysql> show variables like "character_set_database";
+------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name          | Value  |
+------------------------+--------+
| character_set_database | latin1 |
+------------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I create a table in this database, it can't recognize valid utf8 `啊`：

```
mysql> create table t1(name varchar(1) default '啊');
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'name'
```

I know `alter database d1 character set utf8;` will fix this. But I just want **everything default to utf8**, is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried default-character-set=utf8

Comment: @Seb yes, but not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky.

> The character set and collation for the default database can be
>   determined from the values of the `character_set_database` and
>   `collation_database` system variables. The server sets these variables
>   whenever the default database changes. If there is no default
>   database, the variables have the same value as the corresponding
>   server-level system variables, `character_set_server` and
>   `collation_server`.

So one would assume the default for the `collation-database` is the same as the default for the `collation-server` variable.

Please check the following:

1. Is there any other config that would override your my.cnf, like `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf` or `~/.my.cnf` ?
2. The client (not server!) is setting its own collation upon startup, so you could set a client collation/encoding through `[mysql]` (not `mysqld`) or look if this is already set somewhere.
3. You do `SHOW VARIABLES ...` - this is querying `SESSION` based variables, try to query explicitly global settings through `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES ...`

Comment: Is it like this:`[mysql] collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci character-set-server = utf8`?

Comment: I know this is old, but answer is only partial - show what variables? What values should be in which sections of my.cnf (this has changed so many times - it's sickening).

Comment: @DDurham `SHOW VARIABLES` shows **all** variables, but they can be filtered using `LIKE '%character%'` for example. You can read about all this on the page in the comment before from 2016... did you even read it? Stuff hasn't changed in years.