# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, system, migrate

I am trying to create a login system in laravel. 
I've updated env. file with a database called kokodb.
However, when I run this code '**php artisan migrate**' in cmd, I came up with the following error:

**In Connection.php line 647:**

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset unknown to t   he client.
>   Please, report to the developers (SQL: selec   t * from
>   information_schema.tables where table_schema =    kokodb and
>   table_name = migrations)

**In Connector.php line 68:**

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset unknown to t   he client.
>   Please, report to the developers

**In Connector.php line 68:**

> PDO::__construct(): Server sent charset (255) unknown t   o the
>   client. Please, report to the developers

Can you please help me. I did not find any solution to this problem anywhere else.

Comment: What version of PHP and Laravel is this?

Comment: it was version 5. and now it is it is 7.2.11. but this does not solve the problem

Comment: To clarify, it was PHP 5 and then you installed PHP 7.2.11? If so, have you verified that both your webserver and your command line are now using the new php version?

Comment: did you find solotion?

Comment: It seems that upgrading PHP has solved the charset problem. however, now I am facing another problem when I am trying to migrate.  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = kokodb andtable_name = migrations).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of PHP are you using?

According to PHP's bugtracker, this should be fixed as of 7.0.19, 7.1.5, and 7.2.0.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74461

Some answers recommended changing the server charset back to `utf8` from `utf8mb4`, but that is a bad idea. `utf8` doesn't support the full range of valid unicode characters, so trying to save a string that contains certain characters (like some sets of emoji) will cause a database error. It is much better to simply upgrade PHP to a more recent version.

Comment: Alternatively, if upgrading PHP proves too challenging, it might be simpler to downgrade MySQL just below version 8.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you create a database first. then,
Make sure that you have correct params when it comes to the database in your `.env` file. Here scenario for localhost:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306 (this can be different when database changed.)
DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
DB_USERNAME=your_username
DB_PASSWORD=your_pass
```

also run : `php artisan config:cache`
to clear cache.

it work for me.. good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";

$username = "root";

$password = "";



try{

    // servername and database name
    // my port no is 3307 check your's
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host = $servername; dbname=project1; ', $username, $password );


    // set the PDO error mode
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected Successfully";

}
catch(PDOException $e){

    
    echo "Your Connection failed: ".$e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have correct params when it comes to database in your `.env` file. Here scenario for localhost:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
DB_USERNAME=your_username
DB_PASSWORD=your_pass
```

After any change in `.env` use `php artisan config:cache` in console

Also in config/database.php set

```
    'charset'     => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation'   => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'modes'       => [
                'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
                'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
                'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
                'NO_ZERO_DATE',
                'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
                'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
            ],
```

Then also: `php artisan config:cache`

Good luck!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `config:cache` during development

Comment: Hey man, you wouldn't recommend config:cache during development? Maybe you will give us a reason?

Comment: Of course, sorry. If you are *already* caching config then yes, you need to run `config:cache` again (and during deployment). For dev, when config options change often, it's easy to forget that step (and the benefits of optimizing your local machine are small). It can lead to hours of "why won't my change work?" kinds of debugging (the first time). On Stackoverflow I expect there to be a lot of inexperienced Laravel devs who wouldn't remember that they'd run `config:cache` a week ago when they were running commands from suggested fixes. One less pothole for them to step in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version of PHP (for example, 5.6), then you need to downgrade your MySQL version. Version 5 works fine.

However, as PHP 5.6 is now out of support, you should upgrade your PHP and your application, if required.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

1. [PDO::__construct(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437490/pdo-construct-server-sent-charset-255-unknown-to-the-client-please-rep)
2. [Laravel Migration Error: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244541/laravel-migration-error-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1071-specified-key-wa)
3. php artisan make:auth

then

4. php artisan migrate