# Login to MySQL failed (HY000/2054): Server sent charset unknown to the client. What does this mean and how to solve it?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

MySQL Version - 8.0.13.0
PHP Version - 5.6.38
Visual Studio 2017

Just tried to login to MySQL via PHPMyAdmin and it gives me this error, login is correct.

Cannot log in to the MySQL server

mysqli_real_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

Comment: Maybe dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437490/pdo-construct-server-sent-charset-255-unknown-to-the-client-please-rep