# How to install MySql 8 in AWS Linux 1?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

Currently, MySQL 5.5 is installed in Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03. Now I want to upgrade MySQL to the latest version 8.0 and remove old MySQL 5.5 so that I can execute SQL scripts which runs successfully on MySQL 8.

How can we upgrade to MySql 8?
Here is OS details:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
 NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
 VERSION="2018.03"
 ID="amzn"
 ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
 VERSION_ID="2018.03"
 PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
 ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
 CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
 HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

which rhel fedora version is that? So that as per OS version we can download specific MySQL rpm from MySQL server.

Comment: You should backup data, users, roles, after that remove MySQL 5.5 and install MySQL 8.0

Comment: @tiepvut Thanks for your reply. Did you try that?

Comment: yes, i did that.

Comment: @tiepvut Thanks again for the reply. Did you install MySQL 8 on Amazon Linux 1? Can you please which rhel fedora version is Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like that:

```
yum install https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el6-3.noarch.rpm
yum update
```

that will install new source for mysql repo, and then you can go with:

`yum install mysql-community-server`

Comment: It throws this to me: nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mysql-community-server-8.0.11-1.el6.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this and had to figure everything out myself so figure I'd record my process for posterity. To start, make sure you're fully up-to-date. This was my `/etc/os-release` info for the record:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
```

**Upgrade Steps**

1. Run through the upgrade checklist [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrade-prerequisites.html) and obviously backup any critical data and to be extra safe clone the instance and a test-run first. Note that you MUST be running 5.7 currently, and if not then follow the upgrade path documentation. Amazon provides MySQL 5.7 in their default yum repository so this should be straightforward applications of `yum install`/`yum remove` (MySQL offers guides for each 5.5 -> 5.6 -> 5.7 step).
2. Shutdown the current MySQL (upgrade checklist should show you how, but I used `sudo service mysqld stop`).
3. Add the [MySQL yum repository](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html):

   ```bash
   wget https://repo.mysql.com//mysql80-community-release-el6-10.noarch.rpm
   sudo yum localinstall mysql80-community-release-el6-10.noarch.rpm
   ```

   Alternatively, find the latest version at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/.
4. Remove any existing installations:

   ```
   sudo yum remove mysql-config
   sudo yum remove mysql55
   sudo yum remove mysql56
   sudo yum remove mysql57
   ```
5. Install MySQL 8.0:

   ```
   sudo yum install mysql-community-server
   ```
6. Follow the [post-installation setup and testing steps](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/postinstallation.html).
7. Congratulations, you should be up and running with MySQL 8.0. Have fun with your new `WINDOW` & `SUM OVER` capabilities.

**Post-upgrade Notes**

I also had a very old version of PHP running that was having issues connecting after the upgrade (MySQL 8.0 changes the default authentication process and the default server charset and collation to utf8mb4). To fix this, I added the following lines to `my.cnf` and restarted the daemon:

```
[mysqld]

# https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_authentication_plugin
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437490/pdo-construct-server-sent-charset-255-unknown-to-the-client-please-rep
character_set_server=utf8
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
```