# PHP5.6 with MySQL 8 in Amazon RDS

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, character-encoding, amazon-rds

I recently upgraded my database server from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8 because AWS warned me about the end of support for MySQL 5.7. After I upgraded I noticed one of the CakePHP (2.x) apps threw an error saying

```
PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset unknown to the client'
```

1. I tried to view the character set in MySQL 8

```
SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'your_database_name';
> utf8mb3
```

This is strange since the parameter group in AWS says it is utf8mb4
2. I tried to connect on client (CakePHP 2.x) by updating php.ini

```
default_charset = "utf8mb3"
pdo_mysql.default_charset = utf8mb3
```

3. I tried to change it in app/Config/database.php

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'database_name',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8mb3', // Set character set to utf8mb3
    'collation' => 'utf8mb3_general_ci', // Set collation to utf8mb3_general_ci
);
```

Still I am not able to get past this error. Please help me on this

Comment: Perhaps it's time to upgrade your PHP version too, although I appreciate this will be incompatible with your old version of CakePHP. I think this is caused by the server reporting its default character set as utf8mb4 which is not recognised by the client library. Changing the MySQL instance's default charset to utf8 should resolve this issue but the proper solution is to upgrade, as both your PHP and CakePHP versions have been unsupported for a long time. See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43437490/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @user1191247. I am afraid I might not be able to change the charset to utf-8 since it might affect the existing data. Is there a way I can update the charset without affecting the existing data?

Comment: Changing the default character set for the server has no impact on the existing data. It simply changes the default used when no character set is explicitly specified (connection, database, table, column).

Comment: Thank you @user1191247 for your quick response. Can I update the charset on the client side (CakePHP) since my other CakePHP client apps are running fine with the same database server?

Comment: No, it is your version of PHP which is unable to negotiate the connection to the server, as it does not recognise the default character set returned by MySQL. I assume the other working apps are using later versions of both PHP and CakePHP? As long as they are correctly specifying the charset at connection they will not be affected by the default server charset being changed to utf8. What version of PHP and CakePHP are you using? It may be that you can upgrade to a last release of Cake2 and use a later version of PHP.