# How to store encoded values into a DB

Tags: python, mysql, string, utf-8

I want to store an address (type `string`) into a database field (type `VARCHAR`).
The problem is that sometimes the address has **Non-ASCII** characters, so I did the next to take them:

in my .py file

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

# Other imports...

# The connection with the DB
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="myUser", passwd="myPass", db="myDB", charset='utf8', init_command='SET NAMES UTF8')

# More code here...

address2 = address.encode('utf-8')
print "\nTHE ADDRESS TYPE IS -> ", type(address), "\n"
print "\nTHE ADDRESS IS -> ", address, "\n"
print "\nTHE ADDRESS2 IS -> ", address2, "\n"

self.conn.cursor().execute("""INSERT INTO myTable (BLA, BLA, ADDRESS) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", (bla, bla, address2))
# The rest of the code...
```

So when I run the code, I get the following after the `prints`:

```
THE ADDRESS TYPE IS ->  <type 'str'>
THE ADDRESS IS -> Francesc Aragó, 2, 07872 Es Caló, España
THE ADDRESS2 IS -> Francesc Aragó, 2, 07872 Es Caló, España
```

but when I go to my table in the db, and access that field, I get this

```
Francesc Arag?, 2, 07872 Es Cal?, Espa?a
```

I've tried changing the `address2` for `address`in the mysql query, along with many other tries, but I've got nothing so far...

Comment: Perhaps utf-8 is not the default character set in your mysql database. if you start a mysql console and type "show variables like 'char%';", what result do you get?

Comment: What is the collation for the VARCHAR column? Can you alter that column to use a different collation or replace it with an NVARCHAR column?

Comment: @GöranPaues : I've run the command, and this is what I got: `character_set_client -> latin1; character_set_connection -> latin1; character_set_database -> latin1; character_set_filesystem -> binary; character_set_results -> latin1; character_set_server -> latin1; character_set_system -> utf8; character_sets_dir -> /usr/share/mysql/charsets/`

Comment: @TomBlodget : The collation for the varchar column is this one `ADDRESS varchar(255) DEFAULT ''` I didn't create the table, and altering that column might be a difficult option...

Comment: @TomBlodget : But anyway, think like if I could alter the column! What do you mean with NVARCHAR ? sorry, I'm almost new to DataBases...

Comment: `NVARCHAR` is not sufficient.

Comment: `The init_command should have overridden the output from `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'`, so that output is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "question marks" in [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) :

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8/utf8mb4. -- Presumably the `init_command` fixes this.
- The column in the database is CHARACTER SET utf8 (or utf8mb4). -- This seems to be broken.
- Also, check that the connection during reading is UTF-8.

If you have further troubles follow "Test the data" in the above link.

Python tips here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Answer (score 1):

Your database is using latin1, so a solution for your problem is to use UTF-8 in your MySQL database. See this post on how to convert your existing database to UTF-8:
[How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8)

To make sure that your future databases also use utf-8, check this post out on how to change that: [Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf)

You could also use latin1 instead of utf-8 in your Python code, but UTF-8 has become a de facto standard so it's best if your database uses that.

Comment: do you mean all this for this line `character_set_database -> latin1` that showed above?

Comment: That is only one of several things to check.

Comment: yes, that says that your database encoding is latin1, not utf-8.