# Img src not found in html but file_exist in php

Tags: php, html, image, src

I want to upload image that it name in Khmer language.

Ex: `សង្គ្រាមថ្មលោហិត.jpg`.

I uploaded this image to my server and stored the image name in the database.

When I try to fetch this image by using php, it shows nothing, even though the file exists.

In PHP

```
$sql  = mysqli_query($con_database, "select * from Table where id='ID_NUM' ");
$rs = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
$img_name = $rs['Column_Image'];
```

In HTML

```
<img src="<?= $img_name; ?>" >
```

Comment: rename the image before uploading.....

Comment: How are you trying to fetch it? Add the code to your question.

Comment: $sql  = mysqli_query($con_database, "select * from Table where id='ID_NUM' ");
$rs = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
$img_name = $rs['Column_Image'];

In HTML

<img src="<?= $img_name; ?>" >

Comment: Are you able to see the name correctly inserted in the database?

Comment: when I inserted to database it name like this **`ážŸáž„áŸ’áž‚áŸ’ážšáž¶áž˜ážáŸ’áž˜áž›áŸ„áž áž·áž.jpg`** and file image in folder also the same.

Comment: Is the database table and database connection using UTF8?

Comment: @Springie - Yes database table is using UTF8 but I'm not sure about database connection. Can you please tell me how to check my connection using UTF8 or not ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do to set up UTF-8 for a database.

**EXAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
   id    INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   name  VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY(`id`)  

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**DATABASE CONNECTION (PDO)**

Using PDO (note the charset setting).

```
$db_connection = new \PDO("mysql:host=".$db_connection_details['host'].";dbname=".$db_connection_details['database_name'] . ";charset=utf8mb4", $db_connection_details['username'], $db_connection_details['password']);
```

**DATABASE CONNECTION (mysqli)**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

Comment: Thank you Springie! after I set utf8 for database connection, it work properly but for image name still like this **`ážŸáž„áŸ’áž‚áŸ’ážšáž¶áž˜ážáŸ’áž˜áž›áŸ„áž áž·áž.jpg`** while in database show like **`សង្គ្រាមថ្មលោហិត.jpg`**

Comment: Apologies, my example was for PDO, I have added a mysqli example. If it is displaying incorrectly in you HTML you will need to ensure your HTML is output it UTF-8 as well. Here is a great post on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279