# Android posting to C++ REST API having issue with certain data

Tags: c++, mysql, rest

I am working on a project where I have a C++ application which is hosting a REST API. The REST API receives HTTP requests from a library running on android. Various data gets posted to the REST API from the library, one of the items being posted is the device locale.

9 times out of 10 this is perfectly fine but occasionally there is a device where when the C++ parses the HTTP request and then tries to store the locale, the SQL fails.

The Locale that I am receiving in the HTTP request is `%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9`. When I URL Decode this it comes back as `العربية`

That's obviously my problem as its not a normal ASCII string which I'm expecting but I'm not sure the best way to get round it.

Within the C++ app I url decode it using the following:

```
string HTTPRequest::url_decode(string text) {
        char h;
        ostringstream escaped;
        escaped.fill('0');

        for (auto i = text.begin(), n = text.end(); i != n; ++i) {
                string::value_type c = (*i);

                if (c == '%') {
                        if (i[1] && i[2]) {
                                h = from_hex(i[1]) << 4 | from_hex(i[2]);
                                escaped << h;
                                i += 2;
                        }
                }
                else if (c == '+') {
                        escaped << ' ';
                }
                else {
                        escaped << c;
                }
        }

        return escaped.str();
}
```

I then try storing it in the database by using a prepared statement as follows:

`statement->setString(3, this->getLocale().c_str());`

The error I am getting back from MySQL when I try and insert it is:

`Incorrect string value: '\xD8\xA7\xD9\x84\xD8\xB9...' for column 'Locale' at row 1`.

What's the best way to get round this, I was thinking of changing the locale column to a blob, from `varchar(50)` so it  can store it as binary as I'm assuming varchar can only deal with ASCII characters.

Would this be the right away to do this, or is there a better way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the default encoding for MySQL is Latin1. You may want to check your configuration file, and update it accordingly.

[Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf)

Comment: That was the reason, wonder why MySQL defaults to latin1 so I would have thought UTF-8 would be wanted the most to avoid these type of issues

Answer (score 0):

- Declare that your connection is `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or `utf8mb4`).  (I don't know the details on C#; perhaps there is something in http://localhost/rjweb/mysql/doc.php/charcoll .)
- Declare the column in the table to be `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or `utf8mb4`)
- '%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9' into `UNHEX('D8A7D984D8B9D8B1D8A8D98AD8A9')` when inserting.  That is, remove the `%` first.  Also this would work just in SQL: 
  `UNHEX(REPLACE('%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A9', '%', ''))`