# Character Encoding with Java Problems

Tags: java, servlets

I faced utf8 character encoding problem with Java. I read database data 'ঊনত্রিশ' but with java it shows
'ঊনত�?রিশ'. Below my processes

1. My Filter `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`
2. MySQL Connection String is:
   `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8`
3. `model.name = resultSet.getString("name");`
4. `byte[] utf8JsonString = model.name.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`
   `model.name = new String(utf8JsonString);`

I don't know where my faults are.

Comment: `model.name = new String(utf8JsonString);` you're not specifying the charset, so you're using your JVM's default. (Although it's unclear why you convert string to `byte[]` to string).

Comment: Why are you converting `model.name` to bytes and back?

Comment: Has your database correct [UTF-8 settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf)? If you go there by using your favourite client [tool](https://www.eversql.com/top-5-mysql-gui-tools-for-windows/) you see your data with correct encoding?

Comment: @m4gic I test it with node.js & php and output is correct (same database)