# Server Sent Unknown Charset

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver, mysql-8.0

**Background**

I have a script that connects to my MySQL 8 Server and loops through all databases and all tables to export them using mysqldump. I'm doing this as my nightly backup routine and has worked well in the past for previous versions of MySQL.

**Problem**

Now that I am using a new version of MySQL it seems to fail with the following error message:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2054): Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers in C:\wamp\www\mysql-backup-new.php

For reference, I am using mysqli within php version 5.5.12 on Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Can you upgrade PHP, preferably to 7.x?

Comment: Please check setting in mysql configuration file and restart mysql service.
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

Comment: Is that on the server backing up the MySQL server, or the MySQL server itself @Dipti

Comment: mysql config file. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf