# How to save charset settings in mysql server?

Tags: mysql

I have this:

[image]

I want my characterset to be utf8 so I user this command:

```
\g set character_set_server = utf8;
```

And get:

[image]

But when I restart server with \r, charset drops to latin1 again. Am I need some saving command or something?

How I could solve it?

Comment: check the characterset of the database you are connecting, and change it also to utf8 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115612/how-to-convert-an-entire-mysql-database-characterset-and-collation-to-utf-8 but make a backup, this can have unwanted sideeffets

Comment: I can change database settings, but I can't change server settings

Comment: you have to edirt the my.cnf, on every reboot it myslq getws its configuration from there

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf)

Comment: I change setting in my.ini and my server not working anymore. I tried to go back but it still not working

Comment: I solved it by changing my.ini file with notepad++