# How can i change Mysql character_set_system UTF8 to utf8bin

Tags: mysql

When i dump mysql data out , some data has changed because of the character_set_system which is UTF8.Server , client and connection character sete are utf8mb4.

I guess the problem is system character set and server character set differences.

I am trying to change system caharacter set from UTF8 to utf8mb4 with this

[Change MySQL default character set to UTF-8 in my.cnf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513773/change-mysql-default-character-set-to-utf-8-in-my-cnf)

But i can not

Comment: Do not apply permanent change (in `my.ini`). And even global change (`SET GLOBAL ..`). You may break your system in another points. Change needed settings for the current session only with according `SET SESSION variable=value`.

Comment: Thak you for your replay

I am trying to add this to ini , but nothing has change 
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

Comment: *I am trying to add this to ini* Changes made in INI file will be applied during the next MySQL server start. But I strongly recommend you to backup everything (including system and service databases) before this restarting...

Comment: I am very glad for your interest,  when i add this  to conf file                                                     [client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
    
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8mb4   nothing has changed and the character_set_system is still utf8  .  If you succed to change it could you please provide  how can you do this.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The title is incorrectly phrased.

"utf8" is a "character set"

"utf8_bin" is a "collation" for the character set utf8.

You cannot change `character_set...` to collation.  You *may* be able to set some of the `collation_%` entries to `utf8_bin`.

But none of that a valid solution for the problem you proceed to discuss.

*Probably* you can find more tips here:  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

To help you further, we need to see the *symptoms* that got you started down this wrong path.