# Difference between Encoding and collation?

Tags: mysql, encoding

I have seen certain questions and bugs related to `encoding` and `collation`. Could anyone of the visitors explain the difference in `MySQL` domain?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-general.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does character set and collation mean exactly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Encoding refers to that character set used.
Collation determines the sort order.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-general.html

Answer (score 5):

Excellent answers found here, at [programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95048/what-is-the-difference-between-collation-and-character-set):

> collation defines the behaviour of comparison operators: =, >, <, <=, >= ...

Answer (score 0):

I think following qualifies as a better definition for Encoding

> Encoding is an algorithm that translates a list of numbers to binary so it can be stored on disk. For example UTF-8 would translate the number sequence 1, 2, 3, 4 like this: “00000001 00000010 00000011 00000100″.

Source: http://www.calipus.com/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-character-sets-encoding-collations/

Comment: You only answered half of the question, where is the collation part?