# MySQL and PHP: UTF-8 with Cyrillic characters

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm trying to insert a Cyrillic value in the MySQL table, but there is a problem with encoding.

Php:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "a";
$password = "b";
$dbname = "c";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';"); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';"); 
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci';"); 

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE  `c`.`mainp` SET  `search` =  'test тест' WHERE  `mainp`.`id` =1;";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {   
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

MySQL:

```
| id |    search   |            
| 1  |   test Ð°Ð² |
```

Note: PHP file is `utf-8`, database collation `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: You need to stop using `mysql_query()` -- PHP's `mysql_xxx()` functions have been replaced: you should use either the `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries instead. Both of them should make this kind of thing easier to work with.

Comment: Should be the fix for you as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286279/storing-german-special-characters-into-mysql-database

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> You are mixing APIs here, `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` doesn't mix. You should stick with `mysqli_` (as it seems you are anyway), as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, and removed entirely in PHP7.

Your actual issue is a charset problem somewhere. Here's a few pointers which can help you get the right charset for your application. This covers *most* of the general problems one can face when developing a PHP/MySQL application.

- **ALL** attributes throughout your application must be set to UTF-8
- Save the document as UTF-8 w/o BOM (If you're using Notepad++, it's `Format` -> `Convert to UTF-8 w/o BOM`)
- The header in both PHP and HTML should be set to UTF-8

  - **HTML** (inside `<head></head>` tags):

    ```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    ```
  - **PHP** (at the top of your file, before any output):

    ```
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    ```
- Upon connecting to the database, set the charset to UTF-8 for your connection-object, like this (directly after connecting)

  ```
  mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8"); /* Procedural approach */
  $conn->set_charset("utf8");        /* Object-oriented approach */
  ```

  **This is for `mysqli_*`**, there are similar ones for `mysql_*` and PDO (see bottom of this answer).
- Also make sure your database and tables are set to UTF-8, you can do that like this:

  ```
  ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
  ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
  ```

  (Any data already stored won't be converted to the proper charset, so you'll need to do this with a clean database, or update the data after doing this if there are broken characters).

- If you're using `json_encode()`, you might need to apply the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag, otherwise it will convert special characters to their hexadecimal equivalent.

Remember that *EVERYTHING* in your entire pipeline of code needs to be set to UFT-8, otherwise you might experience broken characters in your application.

In addition to this list, there may be functions that has a specific parameter for specifying a charset. The manual will tell you about this (an example is [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)).

There are also special functions for multibyte characters, example: `strtolower()` won't lower multibyte characters, for that you'll have to use `mb_strtolower()`, see this [**live demo**](https://3v4l.org/16R71).

> **Note 1**: Notice that its someplace noted as `utf-8` (with a dash), and someplace as `utf8` (without it). It's important that you know when to use which, as they usually aren't interchangeable. For example, HTML and PHP wants `utf-8`, but MySQL doesn't.
>
> **Note 2**: In MySQL, "charset" and "collation" is not the same thing, see [Difference between Encoding and collation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723648/difference-between-encoding-and-collation). Both should be set to utf-8 though; generally collation should be either `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci`, see [UTF-8: General? Bin? Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2344130/4535200).
>
> **Note 3**: If you're using emojis, MySQL needs to be specified with an `utf8mb4` charset instead of the standard `utf8`, both in the database and the connection. HTML and PHP will just have `UTF-8`.

---

**Setting UTF-8 with `mysql_` and PDO**

- PDO: This is done in the DSN of your object. Note the `charset` attribute,

  ```
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8", "user", "pass");
  ```
- `mysql_`: This is done very similar to `mysqli_*`, but it doesn't take the connection-object as the first argument.

  ```
  mysql_set_charset('utf8');
  ```

Comment: This was the answer for me: 
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
Thanks!!

Comment: Charset can now set with `<meta charset="UTF-8">` as well in the HTML

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

`mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");`  >    `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');`