# Encode � to original char ç

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have a string passed from an API, and in place of certain characters, this appears `�` instead of the original char `ç`. 
I've already tried html_entity_decode, utf8_encode, utf8_decode,htmlentities, etc..

Any idea what I can try? The string is originally encoded in UTF-8

Comment: do you have this on your html page: `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`

Comment: Dont use functions to alter the charset like that, fix the root of the issue instead. There's a little list of things that fixes your issue in 90% of the cases, http://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200

Comment: @BizzyBob Yes. I'm using Laravel, and on the main template there is that

Comment: @Qirel I think I've checked everything. My app has the headers, in both php and html. I have no tables, I'm getting the data from an API from a management program. Don't know what else to do. Isn't there a way to encode the string, besides the functions I already mentiond to just convert the string?

Comment: If you put some static data with those characters (not via the API), is it still broken? If it works with the static data, it likely means there's something with the API, or how you use the API. But check what the file-encoding is too, that can be the issue.