# Russian letters are not displayed correctly in html when read from file

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to read from a .txt file some russian text, but in HTML page it looks awful like a hell.

I added this line to HTML

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Also encoding of my .txt file is UTF-8 (seemingly).

How can I solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: You have a broken charset somewhere in your application, and it could be one of many places. I have previously written [**an answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897407/mysql-and-php-utf-8-with-cyrillic-characters/31899827#31899827) that contains a little checklist, that will cover *most* of the charset issues in a PHP application (it also includes some MySQL parts). There's also a more in-depth topic, [UTF-8 All the Way Through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through). Most likely, you'll find a solution in either one or both of these topics.

Comment: Oh,man, thanks very mush, this helped me!