# How to use UTF-8 for non-English characters in POST method in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post, utf-8

I need to send text from Android to database on server and I'm faced with some question marks for non-English characters.

PHP code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
$con=mysql_connect("xxxxx","xxxxx","123456");
mysql_select_db("xxxxx",$con);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $con);
$user=$_POST['username','utf8'];
$matn=$_POST['matn','utf8'];
$status=$_POST['status','utf8'];
if($user!=""){
    $sqlQ="insert into content(username,matn,status) VALUES('$user','$matn','$status')";
    $result=mysql_Query($sqlQ);
    if($result){
        print "ok";
    }
    else
    {
        print "no";
    }
}else{
    print "-";
}
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: The POST-array doesn't have encoding as a second argument in the index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: yes those utf8 are extra and I delete those but not works

Comment: Set the charset on the connection (`mysql_set_charset()`) too. Any data in the db that's already of the wrong charset won't be fixed though

Comment: I set this but not works , I do not know what  should I do

Comment: Like it says in the dupe, you need to ensure everything is in utf8. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897407/mysql-and-php-utf-8-with-cyrillic-characters/31899827#31899827) has a little checklist for PHP you can follow, but you need to set it in Java too

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the deprecated `mysql_*` interface, use `mysqli_*` or PDO.

What is that second dimension in the array `$_POST`?

The question marks imply that the data was not stored correctly; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored