# UTF-8 '?' symbol with AJAX, PHP,HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, utf-8

so basically i have the following code in `php`:

```
mysqli_query($connect,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($connect,"SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysqli_query($connect,"SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
```

**in `html`:**

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
 <div class="input-group">
   <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name"  value="<?php print $data["name"]; ?>" placeholder="<?php print $data["name"]; ?>">
                                                        </div>
</form>
```

**javascript**:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
  var surname = $('#surname').val();
  var phone_number = $('#phone_number').val();
  var GSM = $('#GSM').val();
  var mail = $('#mail').val();
  var work = $('#work').val();
  var pharmacy_name = $('#pharmacy_name').val();
  var pharmacy_id = $('#pharmacy_id').val(); 
  if($.trim(name).length > 0 && $.trim(surname).length > 0 && $.trim(phone_number).length > 0 && $.trim(GSM).length > 0 && $.trim(mail).length > 0 && $.trim(work).length > 0 && $.trim(pharmacy_name).length > 0 && $.trim(pharmacy_id).length > 0)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"editProfileAction",
    method:"POST",
    data:{name:name, surname:surname},
    cache:false,
....
```

i am using `ajax` to edit `mysql` db but characters such as ıİ,ğĞ are shown as ?? but characters 'çÇüÜ' works fine i tried 3 4 hours trying to fix it i couldn't find an error

Comment: http://www.phptherightway.com/#php_and_utf8 and utf8mb4 for the database

Comment: I have previously written [**an answer about UTF-8 encoding**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200) that contains a little checklist, that will cover *most* of the charset issues in a PHP/MySQL application. 
There's also a more in-depth topic, [UTF-8 All the Way Through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/4535200). Most likely, you'll find a solution in either one or both of these topics.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [post](http://www.phptherightway.com/#php_and_utf8) from php the right way.
For a complete UFT8 support you need to set:

**At the php level:** Put it at the top of your PHP script

```
 <?php
 // Tell PHP that we're using UTF-8 strings until the end of the script
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

**At the database level:**

Your databse collation must be set : **utf8mb4** character set and collation.

> utf8mb4 character set for complete UTF-8 support, not the utf8
>   character set!

**At the browser level**, include

```
 // Tell PHP that we'll be outputting UTF-8 to the browser
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
```

and for the html part

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: it works in html output but now values in my database gives are such as Ä±Ä° i used utf8mb4 as you said