# PHP auto encodes text in production server

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I have developped a php website in wamp on Windows 7 64bit. Then i have hosted it on 00webhost. The problem is that in my dev environment all characters with accents work properly but in production it shows like that Ã©gÃ©. Also in my dev environment text appears like Ã©gÃ© in database but in the production it appears like éè
To handle this i have various solutions like executing "SET NAMES utf8" after opening a connexion to the database, setting mb_internal_encoding to utf8, and others. But none work.
I am not a php guru so can you explain why this difference and how to overcome this.

Comment: I have previously written [**an answer about UTF-8 encoding**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200) that contains a little checklist, that will cover *most* of the charset issues in a PHP/MySQL application. 
There's also a more in-depth topic, [UTF-8 All the Way Through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/4535200). Most likely, you'll find a solution in either one or both of these topics.

Comment: i have done all of that. one fact is that i have uploaded it i a previous server and it works correctly. see http://mboatek.cf and http://mboatek.com it is the same code.

Comment: Keep in mind that the data already in the database will not be automatically converted. That will still be broken. If the data in the database is correctly encoded, then there's a step you missed somewhere. All it takes is one step, and it breaks ;-)

Comment: data are the same. i have look directly to the database. do you confirm differences in the 2 websites?

Comment: No, I haven't looked - because it'll most likely not help anways, as the code (PHP) isn't readable by the client anyways. If you are 100% sure the data in the database is correctly encoded, then you haven't followed all the steps (set UTF8 in the MySQL connection, file, headers in PHP and HTML, database-columns, etc).

Comment: See "Mojibake" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored