# Character encoding issue using php Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, multilingual

I am using a multilingual feature in one of my project and having a following issue.

1) Words,characters doesn't display properly on frontend.

The mysql table collation is set to  "utf_8_general_ci"

I got the following output on frontend.

> ÙˆØ§Ù‚Ø¹ÛŒ , Ù¾ÙˆÙ„ , Ø¨Ø§ÛŒØ¯

I have also placed this in header tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Can you guys please have a look at this.

Comment: is the table also in that encoding? what about your IDE? The PHP files?

Comment: table is set to utf_8_general_ci @delboy1978uk

Comment: Charset isn't the same as collation! Run a `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` and see what the charset is. You also need to check the PHP header.

Comment: This is what i have got from show create table command @Qirel
https://ibb.co/jZg2KQ

Comment: And what's the PHP header? FIle-encoding? Connection-encoding? As you see, there are many settings that needs to be specified. See the flagged dupe, or [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897407/mysql-and-php-utf-8-with-cyrillic-characters/31899827#31899827) with a little checklist of things to set to UTF8. I'm sure you'll find a solution in either one or both of these.

Comment: Thank you,i will look into this @Qirel