# How can I print Scandinavian characters (åäö) correctly when using MySQL and PHP MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How do I handle Scandinavian characters when using MySQLi? Text `Päivänkakkara` is now printed as `P\u00e4iv\u00e4nkakkara` in the browser.

I'm using the `set_charset` function like below when initializing the database connection:

```
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
```

The collation of the table is `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Comment: Put this in your head tag `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: All it takes, is one wrong charset setting in your application - *everything* needs to be the same charset! I have previously written [**an answer about UTF-8 encoding**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200) that contains a little checklist, 
that will cover *most* of the charset issues in a PHP/MySQL application. 
There's also a more in-depth topic, [**UTF-8 All the Way Through**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/4535200). Most likely, you'll find a solution in either one or both of these topics.

Comment: `P\u00e4iv\u00e4nkakkara` looks like you're encoding of sorts (that's unicode), do you have `json_encode()` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `json_encode`. Do I have to manually decode the JSON (I'm using PHP via AJAX)?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the text to print correctly by using

```
echo json_encode($foo, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Then, however, I have to explicitly parse the JSON client-side. My client is written in TypeScript, so:

```
JSON.parse(data);
```