# Setting character set on MySQL connection does not work

Tags: php, mysql, character-set

I am trying to set a very simple [session connection variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html) on MySQL, but it doesn't do anything. The queries run below do not cause any errors, but the character set of the MySQL connection won't be changed. If I configure the default values for 'collation_server' and 'character_set_server' in the `my.ini` file as `utf8mb4` instead of `latin1`, then the character set becomes `utf8mb4`, but I wonder why I cannot change the connection character set from my PHP script.

```
$pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost", "root", "");
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$pdo->query("SET NAMES utf8mb4");

print_r($pdo->query("SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

This query shows that the `SET NAMES` statement did not have affect.

Comment: Each query will stand on it's own. Take a look at [PHP Manual Multiple Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)

Comment: Try putting `charset=utf8mb4` in the DSN instead.

Comment: @SloanThrasher This is PDO, not mysqli.

Comment: The `GLOBAL VARIABLES` is still set to what it is.

Comment: I've previously written an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827 that details the charset of a PHP application with a database. There's also the more in depth topic here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through - if you take your time to read them, you'll find your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES` to see the changes, not `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES`.

`SET NAMES` doesn't change GLOBAL variables. It only changes the character set variables for your current session.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html says:

A SET NAMES 'charset_name' statement is equivalent to these three statements:

```
SET character_set_client = charset_name;
SET character_set_results = charset_name;
SET character_set_connection = charset_name;
```

Those statements change session variables only.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. I copied the `SHOW VARIABLES` statement from stackoverflow and overlooked the word `GLOBAL`.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the charset for the session (not global). Try

```
SHOW SESSION VARIABLES WHERE ...
```

Note that with PDO you can set the character set as part of the DSN:

```
$pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8mb4", "root", "");
```