# Japanese character encoding issue on web browser

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, character-encoding

When I query in MySQL then it returns in Japanese Character. An image is attached below.

[image]

But in browser its shown "**????**". An image is attached below.
[image]

Here I enclose my base.html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link media="screen" href="<?php echo $this->path_to('/common/css/import.css') ?>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="<?php echo $this->path_to('/common/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js') ?>"></script>
<title><?php echo $this->v('page_title') ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $this->part_of('body') ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: You need to set your charset, and UTF8 should work. See the flagged duplicate above, or [**this answer** I have previously written](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200) about UTF8, which contains a nice little checklist for the most things that needs to have a specified charset in a PHP/MySQL application.

Comment: Thanks all. I solved the problem as given below.

SELECT column1, CAST(CONVERT(column2 USING utf8) AS binary)
FROM my_table
WHERE my_condition;

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_set_charset($db,'utf8');` in your dbconnection file. in my case $db is my connection variable