# Cannot convert string in utf8

Tags: php, encoding

I have this string: `Deportivo La Coruña`, if I return it I'll get: `Deportivo la coruÃ±a`, so I tried to handle the encoding in this way:

```
$homeName = "Deportivo La Coruña";
return mb_convert_encoding($homeName, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8'),
```

but same problem. I tried also `utf8_encode` but same result. How can I fix this issue without installing external libs?

Comment: Could you clarify "return"?

Comment: All it takes, is one wrong charset setting in your application - *everything* needs to be the same charset! I have previously written [**an answer about UTF-8 encoding**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200) that contains a little checklist, 
that will cover *most* of the charset issues in a PHP/MySQL application. 
There's also a more in-depth topic, [**UTF-8 All the Way Through**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/4535200). Most likely, you'll find a solution in either one or both of these topics.

Comment: @Qirel I'm using Slim, I'm developing an API

Comment: @RolandStarke `return` is used inside a function for return a value that could be an integer, a boolean, or as in this case a string.

Comment: @utop Sounds like you got a broken charset somewhere in your application. Go through the two posts I linked. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the `$homeName = "Deportivo La Coruña";` is in `ISO-8859-1`

```
return mb_convert_encoding($homeName,  'ISO-8859-1' ,'UTF-8');
```

Use this to achieve your result.